# Why Limit FPS with Specific Values

Tags: game-engine, frame-rate

Many games(or engines) has limited FPS which can be 30, 60 or 90?

So, Why should they choose those specific values?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question. It would be a better fit on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't limited to those specific values, they are limited to the vertical sync of the screen/monitor which generally do run at 60Hz.

Comment: For one, that's not true because users can turn off vsync on a desktop OS. Second, the reason why some games (specifically on consoles) limit themselves to 30 fps is to have more time for each frame while providing a stable framerate. It's typically a better experience for players if the framerate is locked to 30 fps (specifically with added motion blur to compensate for the lack of smoothness) rather than sometimes rendering 30 fps and in other scenes running smoothly at 60 fps, or even with vsync off fluctuating anywhere between 30 to 60 fps.

Comment: It was more of a general answer to a general question. Basically those numbers are picked because they are multiples of the frame rate. On consoles back in the 80/90s the OP would have seen in PAL running territories the frame rate at 25 or 50 fps.